# library search pathsについて

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

現在`CocoaPods`を使ってライブラリを取り込み、プロジェクトをビルドしようとしたのですが、 「linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)」というエラーが出てビルドが失敗してしまいます。 `Link Binary With Libraries`には`CocoaPods`でインストールしたライブラリの`.aファイル`が追加されています。（ちなみにこの`.aファイル`とは一体なんでしょうか...？） そして色々と調べたところ、`library search paths`を設定しなければならないようですが、この`library search paths`とは一体なんなのでしょうか？ ライブラリを使う時に、プロジェクト側に使うライブラリがどこにあるか分からせるためのものでしょうか？ しかしここにパスを設定しなくてもライブラリを組み込んだプロジェクトを実行できた記憶があるのですが......（それとも`CocoaPods`でライブラリを組み込んだ時に自動でパスが設定されていた？） また、プロジェクトをFinderで開きPodフォルダに行くと`CocoaPods`でインストールしたライブラリのフォルダ達があるのですが、ここのパスを`library search paths`に設定してあげればいいのでしょうか？絶対パスで指定してみたもののずっと「linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)」のエラーが出ているのでよくわかりません...。 どのように`library search paths`を設定すればよろしいでしょうか？ どなたかわかる方がいれば教えていただきたいです。よろしくお願いします。

ちなみに「linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)」のエラーを消すために以下の記事なども参考にしたのですがうまくいきませんでした。

[Xcodeで「ld: library not found for -l○○」が出続ける](https://blog.tagbangers.co.jp/ja/2015/12/03/Xcode_library_not_found_for_marumaru)

[Xcode5でCocoaPodsを追加したらLinker Errorが出た際の対処法](http://qiita.com/u651601f/items/de2cc28ea8fe36f48a70)

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

結局`CocoaPods`からではなくライブラリをダウンロードしてXcodeに手動で追加することで問題が解決できたのですが、今度は別のライブラリ（`CocoaPods`から追加したライブラリ）で
「Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_クラス名"」
というエラーが出ました。
またこれもダウンロードしてXcodeに手動で追加して解決しようかと思うのですが、これでは`CocoaPods`が使えません^^;
まず`Link Binary With Libraries`にライブラリの`.aファイル`は追加されています。
しかし、プロジェクトナビゲータにある追加したライブラリの`.aファイル`と`libPods.a`というファイルは赤文字になっています。これが怪しいような気がするのですが、`Link Binary With Libraries`からライブラリを削除して再追加してみても赤文字のままです。
`library search paths`で正しくパスを設定しなければならないのでしょうか？しかし`CocoaPods`から追加したライブラリのパスはどこになるんでしょうか？
色々調べまくって`Build Active Architecture Only`のYes/Noを変更したり、`Enable Bitcode`のYes/Noを変更したりと機能について理解してないまま片っ端から解決策を試しているのですが、新たなエラーが出たりともうお手上げ状態です。。。
...どうすればよろしいでしょうか？

Comment: `pod install`の後に作成されるワークスペース(*.xcworkspace)を開いていますか？プロジェクトファイルを開いていませんか？

Comment: はい、.xcworkspaceを開いているのですがエラーは出続けています。。。